# Testing of Raw HTTP post in java, 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, network-programming

I have developed a raw http post in java. I am trying to post a file to the post request dump website http://www.posttestserver.com/. But it shows and error 
400 Bad Request. Pleas let me know what need to be done to avoid this error.

In this code , output => Stream to write on server.
filename -> path on server, here filename is initated to post.php

```
    output.println("POST"+" "+filename+" HTTP/1.1\r");
            //output.println("Content-Length: "+data.length());
            output.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x\r");
            output.println("Content-length: 100\r");
            //As http1.1 is by default keep-alive , close the connection explicitly
            output.println("Connection: Close");   
            // blank line 
            output.println();   
            output.println("--AaB03x");         
            output.print( 
            "--AaB03x Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileID\"; filename=\"temp.txt\" Content-Type: text/plain "
            +"/nHello How are you?" 
            + "/n--AaB03x--");
            output.flush();
```

> **Error is**
>
> **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**
>
> **Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 02:22:00 GMT**
>
> **Server: Apache**
>
> **Vary: Accept-Encoding**
>
> **Content-Length: 226**
>
> **Connection: close**
>
> **Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1**
>
> **400 Bad Request**
>
> ## Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue of Content type. Server is expecting a request having header of content type text/HTML but your request content type is multipart/form data.